rqpd package general questions
I'm using the rqpd package to run quantile regressions in a panel setting.
I have 2 questions:

Is there a way to plot the coefficients, along with confidence intervals?
How do I get the bootstrapping function to work?

My code so far looks like this
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm");

model1= value ~ inv | firm

p=panel(method="pfe", taus=1:9/10, tauw=rep(0.1, 9), 
      lambda=1, cre="m", ztol=1e-5)

model1_qr= rqpd(model1, panel= p, data = Grunfeld)

summary.rqpd(model1_qr)
print.rqpd(model1_qr)

coefs1=coef.rqpd(model1_qr)


Thanks!
